# how format a usb drive in the right way? (FAT 32 to NTFS)

Tags: usb, disk-space, format, hard-drive

I bought two usb drives (8 GB) a few days ago.   One of them is HP a v245L - 8 GB and the other one is a Silicon Power - 8GB.  Their format was FAT32, so i reformatted them to ntfs with my windows 7 without using any third party software with the full format option

It seems there is a problem with both of them  - Their used space is about 66 MB instead of 0.
This is a screenshot of the drive's properties:
[image: one of their pictures]

thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I also think after reformatting their speed became slower.

Comment: You will also notice what you have to use "Safely remove hardware". Manufacturers are formatting them to FAT32 for purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you format any partition with NTFS (or Fat32) it reserves some space for the Master File Table (MFT). This structure allows the driver to map available phsyical sectors to logical files. Its what formatting a drive builds.

Comment: really thanks for answer. but what is going on about their speed?  plz see my edit.

Comment: @SilverLight - You used the words "I think" which tell me one of two things.  The speed was actually effected or it wasn't.  Until you actually confirm what "you think" we cannot help you.  There is no technical reason the drivers would slower.

Comment: ok bro, thanks for attention.now as you said those used spaces are normal. am i right?